# TIBCO automated build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, build-automation, tibco, automated-deploy

I am really new to TIBCO environment, and I am working on TIBCO BW.
I really want to know the concept "how to build and deploy TIBCO".
Various books told me that TIBCO Admin will deploy and manage after I finish developing in TIBCO Designer. However, my mentor pointed out that I am going to use TIBCO AMX(3.2?) and my project will be setting up 'automated build' (Yes! I have no idea!)

1) building and deployment concept of TIBCO using AMX

2) any suggestion or article or blog for 'automated build'?

Thanks a lot!!

P.S
If you are also interested in TFS automated build, please have a look at the link below!

[VS2010 TFS Automated build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222332/vs2010-tfs-automated-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For automating the TIBCO build and deploy, read about the build-ear command and appmanage command available from the TRA.

Check the TRA documentation that you will get when you install TIBCO for details/options.

You can use this with ANT or Maven and have the script run automatically.

Also of interest might be [TIBant](http://windyroad.org/software/open-source/tibant/)

M

Comment: I am now using ANT to make automated build for TIBCO. Thanks!