# VS2010 TFS Automated build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, build-automation, tibco, automated-deploy

I have 'fair' experience about VS and TFS environment.
Here is what I have done so far. After I finished the coding work, I built it, checked-in it and other guy deployed it.
So, I don't know what the meaning of 'automated build'..
what is 'automated build'? and how can i make it? 
If you can attach some example files, that would be much appreciated it.

Thank you very much

Oh! I am also working on TIBCO automated build, so if you are interested in please have a look via link below!

[TIBCO automated build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221994/tibco-automated-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the concept: Continous Integration.
For your platform, look up: tfs build controller, tfs build agent and msbuild.